# What is the geometrical definition of the $\sec\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

This is the geometrical definition of the $\sec\theta$:

[image]

My problem with this definition is when the angle $\theta$ is in the forth quadrant. The $\sec \theta$ is positive but the geometrical representation of the $\sec \theta$ is below the $x$ axis.

Comment: X axis isn't relevent for sec =1/cos. It positive iff it is to the left of the y axis; just like cos is.

Answer (score 4):

Think of the line that is tangent to the unit circle. The $x-$intercept of that tangent line (that is, the point where the line cuts the $x-$axis) is the secant of that angle. It should be more clear why the secant is positive on the $1$st and the $4$th quadrant.

I found this picture on the internet:

[image]

Comment: Quite a wonderful picture.

Answer (score 1):

The secant is positive when the cosine is positive,
that is, when the geometric representations of these functions
are to the right of the $y$-axis.
The position of the geometric representations relative to the $x$-axis
do not determine whether these functions are positive or negative.